instead of lh3000 i'm getting Local: http://localhost:5173/ i cant open my page can somebody help me
I'm trying to create my web page but I'm stuck.
Can you tell me how to set it up so I can access localhost:3000? I'm really not sure what to do. All I'm getting is ➜ Local: http://localhost:5173/ which is the home page of my Vite app. Instead of this, I want my page to be accessible at localhost:3000. Can someone please tell me the solution? Also, can you explain why I'm getting ➜ Local: http://localhost:5173/ when I enter the command npm run dev?

I'm sorry, but I cannot tell from your explanation what is going on.  Do you have a server?  How did you configure it?  Why did you expect it to listen on 3000?

im following up a tutorial  and in that he  got  link of localhost 3000 whereas I'm getting  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/

Please look at [ask]

Link to Vite config server options. Basically you need to add server: { port: 3000 } to your config. (I also find the open: true option useful too.)

5143 is the default value of the Vite server.port.
Check the port value in vite.config.js , you can reconfigure it to your desired port.
